# How can I get an argument from error for discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to get an argument like in the image below:

[image]

My code:

```
class Admin(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def purge(self, ctx, amount: int):
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount+1)

    @purge.error
    async def purge_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
            await ctx.send('Please enter a number.')
        elif isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
            await ctx.send('This is not a number.')
```

How can I do it?

Comment: If you just sent the error you would get `Converting to "int" failed for parameter "amount".` aka the lib handles it for you in the backend. Not really the exact format you want but seems it's the easiest solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`commands.BadArgument`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.BadArgument) is not passed the [`inspect.Parameter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Parameter) that other exceptions like [`commands.MissingRequiredArgument`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.MissingRequiredArgument) have as a `param` attribute.

If you're trying to get the parameter name for `MissingRequiredArgument`, you can just use that attribute and [`Parameter.name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Parameter.name).

Otherwise, `BadArgument` is usually passed a message. [The most common case for this](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/195b5188e8707d14d8b43aa31c3fc4628e0c370b/discord/ext/commands/core.py#L417) is a string that contains the `Parameter.name` in the form `'Converting to "{}" failed for parameter "{}".'.format(name, param.name)` where `name` is the converter name and `param` is the `Parameter`, and parsing that is likely how the bot in your image is getting it. In this case, you can get this message by casting the `BadArgument` to a string or as the first and only argument in the tuple returned by the exception's `args` attribute. See [Python's documentation on handling exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) for more detail.

Note though, that `BadArgument` can be raised for reasons other than an integer conversion and with different or no messages, e.g. for boolean converters, Discord converters, custom converters, etc.